# Equations of motions vs Verlet: Collision ignored?

Tags: forces, simulations, integration

I initially coded my simulation using the standard equations of motions, but as is known, it ended up being quite unstable, even if it *technically* worked.

If we take x(t) to be the position-function of the equations of motion, I calculated my "next" position in the simulation by re-factoring x(t+delta), as follows:

```
x(t+delta) = x(t) + (1/2)*a*delta^2 + a*t*delta
t = t + delta
```

Most importantly, a is calculated as NetForce/Mass. If my system/particle encounters a collision, a normal force influences the net force in such a way that it is 0 on the axis of the collision (ie if it falls on the ground, force of gravity is pulling down, normal force of floor cancels gravity). *So far, this has worked splendidly with any kind of collision.*

However, I decided to switch to Verlet integration as it is known to be more stable, and for some reason, it completely ignores collision. I use the following formulas:

```
x(t+delta) = x(t) + v(t) * delta + .5*a(t)*delta^2
v(t+delta) = v(t) + .5 * (a(t) + a(t+delta)) * delta
a(t+delta) = NetForce / Mass
t = t + delta
```

Where v(0)=0, a(0)=0. As such, in addition to old position, I also store old acceleration and velocity.
However, I get the aforementioned problem: It just doesn't work properly, as it ignores collision. Even though it should be factored in into the acceleration already... The problem lies therein that my acceleration is 0 (obviously) in the moment of collision, but Verlet is not purely a product of acceleration. As such, it continues moving my particles even when they might have 0 acceleration at a specific moment.

How should I approach this?